# Running a code after Timer finished or Canceled

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

[image]
**Follow the Path Game Description:**
in this game there are some squares in the screen all invisible(in our case 9), a random sequence of them start to show up in the screen(we only show 4 here). and the user have to select the squares by the order they are shown in the screen.

**What are the problems?:**
1. user should not be allowed to choose a square during reveal. i can disable the buttons but how to enable them after timer finishes? i can't find a postLaunch or timerCanceled event to enable the buttons for selection again?
2. after user games over the game should start again automatically in 1sec. if i use Thread.sleep(1000) after settingBackgroundColor() it will give me the 1sec but ignores setBackground(). i want user to see the wrong answer(incorrectColor background) before game resets.

**Codes:**

```
// allSquares, generatedSquares,generationSpeed can be used to change game difficulty
int allSquares = 9;
int generatedSquares = 4;
int generationSpeed = 500;
Button[] buttons = new Button[allSquares];
@IdRes
int[] ids = {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7, R.id.b8, R.id.b9};
Button bGenerate;
List<Integer> randomOrder;
int selectedSquare = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bGenerate = findViewById(R.id.bGenerate);
    bGenerate.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void runAlgorithm()
{
    // initiate + invisible all squares
    for (int i = 0; i < allSquares; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
        buttons[i].setAlpha(0.0f);
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.squareColor));
        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
    }

    // generate random sequence
    randomOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    randomOrder.clear();
    Random random = new Random();
    while (randomOrder.size() < generatedSquares)
    {
        int generatedNumber = random.nextInt(allSquares);
        if (!randomOrder.contains(generatedNumber))
        {
            randomOrder.add(generatedNumber);
            Log.i("FollowThePath", generatedNumber + "");
        }
    }

    // show random sequence by order
    final int[] counter = {0};
    selectedSquare = 0;
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            buttons[randomOrder.get(counter[0])].setAlpha(1.0f);
            counter[0]++;
            if (counter[0] == generatedSquares)
            {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, generationSpeed);
    // Bug 1: need to enable buttons after timer finishes, user should not be allowed to choose a square during square reveal
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bGenerate)
        runAlgorithm();
    else
    {
        Log.i("FollowThePath", v.getTag().toString() + "       " + randomOrder.get(selectedSquare));
        if (v.getTag().toString().equals(randomOrder.get(selectedSquare).toString()))
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correctColor));
            v.setEnabled(false);
            selectedSquare++;
        } else
        {
            // Game Over
            Toast.makeText(this, "You failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Bug: setBackground executes so fast
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrectColor));
            // Bug 2: we need a delay here, so that user sees the incorrect color and gets ready for next game
            // Thread.sleep(1000) ignores the color change, it means user can't see incorrectColor even if i add a Thread.sleep after that
            // starting a new game
            runAlgorithm();
        }
        if (selectedSquare == generatedSquares)
        {
            // Succeeded
            // Toast.makeText(this,"You did it.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // run a new game
            runAlgorithm();
        }
    }
}

private void enableAllButtons(boolean enable)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allSquares; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you already enabled the buttons in your initial for-loop. I thought you only wanted to enable them after the TimerTask was complete.

Comment: @tvicky4j247 i enabled it because i couldn't do it after Timer(Bug 1). other wise yes, it should be false in for loop, but enabling them for user after timer finishes, the problem is the 2nd part how to enable them after timer finishes?

Comment: @tvicky4j247 edited setEnabled() from true to false to avoid further misunderstandings.

Comment: Ok nice. I've added an answer, see if that helps with the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first problem, since the only way for the `TimerTask` to finish is when it gets cancelled based on this condition `counter[0] == generatedSquares`, then all you need to do is something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   buttons[randomOrder.get(counter[0])].setAlpha(1.0f);
   counter[0]++;
   if (counter[0] == generatedSquares)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                enableAllButtons(true);
            }
        });
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

For the second problem, the color change might not be showing up because the algorithm to restart kicks off too quickly and since all this is on the UI Thread, using `Thread.sleep(1000)` doesn't help. Try wrapping the `runAlgorithm()` call in something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //what ever you do here will be done after 500 mili seconds delay.
        runAlgorithm();
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
```

Hopefully that works since I can't test it.

Comment: I tried that before, but my stupidity was that i didn't read the error correctly. just update your answer to this and we are done about the first problem. 
if (counter[0] == generatedSquares)
{
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
 {
          @Override
 public void run()
 {
          enableAllButtons(true);
        }
 });
 timer.cancel();
}

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi Ooh nice. Ok, one to go. The second one is a little tricker, try wrapping the `runAlgorithm()` call in a non-repeating `TimerTask` that delays for one second.

Comment: it works if i add a new Timer with onUIThread again after setBackground. but i'm not sure this is the right way to do it, cuz it isn't just 2 timer. they are calling each other inside them, which means it recurring each other, makes further debuggins hard, but it works now, just was looking for some thing similar to Thread.sleep()

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi calling each other? Can I see what it looks like now?

Comment: i meant the lifecycle for the 2nd timer isn't clear, or i don't understands it, when is it finished or cancels? found below solution, seems more clear. what do you think?
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
     public void run()
     {
      //what ever you do here will be done after 500 mili seconds delay.
      runAlgorithm();
     }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 500);

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi Oh yeah, that works the same way as this TimerTask. So the TimerTask code I put up there executes only once, after the specified delay of 1000 milliseconds. Look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)). So you don't need to stop or cancel it yourself. It runs only once.

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi The only thing I'd say is to wrap the contents of your `runAlgorithm` and `enableAllButtons` methods in a `runOnUiThread` call since they might get called from all sorts of places/threads. That way, you don't need to always have to use the `runOnUIThread` thing everytime you call those methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199525/discussion-between-masoud-mohammadi-and-tvicky4j247).